# If two sequences $u_n,v_n$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} u_n=a,\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} v_n=b$

Tags: limits

Given two sequences $u_n$ and $v_n$ such that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} u_n=a$ and $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} v_n=b$, define $x_{n}= \max\{u_n,v_n\}$ and $y_n=\min\{u_n,v_n\}$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n=\max\{a,b\}$ and $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n=\min\{a,b\}$.

This is trivial if the sequences are monotonic. But gets complicated slightly if thet are not given to be monotonic.

Comment: I assume you cannot use the fact that $(x,y)\mapsto\max(x,y)$ is continuous?

Comment: Thinking around the problem, I personally don't see why monotonicity would make it any easier.

Comment: Good point. I can't see it either. (Maybe the OP meant $x_n \leq y_n$ for all $n$ instead?)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$\max\{u_n,v_n\}=\frac{1}{2}\big(u_n+v_n+|u_n-v_n|\big)$$   $$\min\{u_n,v_n\}=\frac{1}{2}\big(u_n+v_n-|u_n-v_n|\big)$$

Can you conclude now?

Comment: How will it help?

Comment: Take the limit both sides. Do you know $x \to \vert x \vert$ is continuous?

Comment: Can you explain how the rhs becomes $\max(a,b)$?

Comment: Can you tell me what do you get after applying limits on RHS?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the $\textbf{idea}$ for $\,"\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=\max(a,b)"\,$:

If $\,a=b\,$ then it is obvious that $\,x_n\rightarrow\max(a,b)\,$ because both $\,u_n$ and $\,v_n$ are convergent to $a=b=\max(a,b)$

If $\,a\neq b$, then WLOG, suppose $\,a>b$. Then as $\,n\,$ increases, $\,u_n$ will get closer and closer to $\,a\,$ while $\,v_n$ will get closer and closer to $\,b$. As a result, there exists a point beyond which every $\,u_n$ will be greater than $\,v_n$. Thus, beyond that point, we have $\,x_n=\max(u_n,v_n)=u_n\,$ and it becomes easy to show $\,x_n\rightarrow a=\max(a,b)\,$

$\left.\right.$

If you are still confused, here is the $\textbf{proof}$ for $\,"\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=\max(a,b)"\,$:

$\left.\right.$

If $\,a\neq b$, then WLOG, we assume that $\max(a,b)=a$ and fix $\,\varepsilon=\frac{a-b}2>0\,$

Since $\,\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}u_n=a\,$ and $\,\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}v_n=b$, we have

$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\exists N_u\in\mathbb R\ \ \text{such that}\ \ \forall n\in\mathbb N:(n>N\ \Rightarrow|u_n-a|<\varepsilon)\qquad\qquad(\rm I)$$

$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \exists N_v\in\mathbb R\ \ \text{such that}\ \ \forall n\in\mathbb N:(n>N\ \Rightarrow|v_n-b|<\varepsilon)\qquad\qquad(\rm II)$$

Next, we get

$$\qquad\qquad u_n>a-\varepsilon=\frac{a+b}2\qquad\text{by (I)}$$
$$\qquad\qquad\  v_n<b+\varepsilon=\frac{a+b}2\qquad\text{by (II)}$$

(I) and (II) together shows

$$\forall n\in\mathbb N:\ n>\max(N_u,N_v)\ \Rightarrow\ u_n>\frac{a+b}2>v_n\ \Rightarrow\ x_n=\max(u_n,v_n)=u_n$$

This means that $\,x_n$ will be the same as $\,u_n$ if $\,n>\max(N_u,N_v)$, and it becomes obvious to show that $\,x_n\rightarrow a$

---

If $\,a=b$, then $\,a=\max(a,b)$. Hence $\,\forall\varepsilon>0\,$ we have

$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\exists N_u\in\mathbb R\ \ \text{such that}\ \ \forall n\in\mathbb N:(n>N\ \Rightarrow|u_n-a|<\varepsilon)\qquad\qquad(\rm I)$$

$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \exists N_v\in\mathbb R\ \ \text{such that}\ \ \forall n\in\mathbb N:(n>N\ \Rightarrow|v_n-a|<\varepsilon)\qquad\qquad(\rm II)$$

Now simply let $\,n>\max(N_u,N_v)\,$ and we can show that $\,|x_n-a|<\varepsilon\,$ and thus $\,x_n\rightarrow a=\max(a,b)\,$

$\left.\right.$

Now use the same trick for $\,\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_n=\min(a,b)$